# Lua library doesn't linking

Tags: c++, lua, g++, mingw, linker-errors

I get `undefined reference to 'luaL_openlibs'` when I try to execute the following code

```
extern "C"
{
#include "../lib/lua.h"
#include "../lib/lualib.h"
#include "../lib/lauxlib.h"
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my VSCode tasks file:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\**.cpp",
                "-L",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\lib",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\debug\\game.exe",
                "-llua54"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

these are my files

```
.
├── .vscode
│   ├── c_cpp_properties.json
│   └── launch.json
│   └── settings.json
│   └── tasks.json
├── debug
├── lib
│   ├── lauxlib.h
│   └── lua.h
│   └── lua.hpp
│   └── luaconf.h
│   └── lualib.h
│   └── liblua54.dll
│   └── liblua54.a
├── src
│   ├── main.cpp
```

as I can see, I specified all necessary parameters for compiler. I'm complete begginer to linking libraries and I don't know what I'm missing.

I also tryed to move liblua54.a and liblua54.dll to the debug folder, but it didn't help.

Comment: Why are you doing `#include "../lua/lualib.h"` if `lualib.h` is in a directory called `lib`, not `lua`? (And similarly for the other headers)

Comment: I just made a mistake when writing minimal reproducible example. it's lib folder in my program.

Comment: So the minimal reproducible example you posted here isn't what you actually tried? Please try using exactly what you posted here and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Just tried it and got the same error

Comment: Did you compile the Lua library yourself? If so, how? If not, where did you get it?

Comment: I get it from http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: You refer to the `lauxlib.h` but do not have this file in `lib` dir.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That was yet another typo in the post of the directory tree, judging by the OP's edit, and not actually the case on disk.

Comment: oh, sorry, I made mistake when writing file hierarchy. There is lauxlib.h actually

Comment: just tried building lua by myself but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 32-bit and 64-bit mixed up. If your gcc builds 32-bit executables, then you need to use the 32-bit binaries from http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html, not the 64-bit ones. When I mixed these up on purpose, I got the exact error that you're getting, and when I used the right ones, it compiled fine.

Answer (score -2):

I expect that adding the following to `args` above will help:

```
...
"${workspaceFolder}\\lua",
"-l",
"-llua56",
 "-o",
...
```

Comment: `-l` by itself won't do anything, and the OP already have `-llua54` in the options list.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Right you are.