# Lua 5.4 undefined reference with GCC

Tags: c, windows, gcc, lua

I'm trying to use gcc to dynamically link to the lua library but I keep getting undefined references to every single lua function, including luaL_newstate.

Here's the code I'm trying to compile

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    lua_State *state = luaL_newstate();
    lua_close(state);
    return 0;
 }
```

And here's the command I'm using

```
cls && gcc test.c -Ilua-5.4.2_Win64_dllw6_lib\include -Llua-5.4.2_Win64_dllw6_lib -llua54
```

I also tried static linking with `-l:liblua54.a`, changing the order of the parameters, and moving the files into the mingw64 include and lib folders and using those instead, but nothing seems to change anything.

Comment: Is that the *only* message you get? When asking questions about build error, always please include the full and complete build log (as it might contain other information that could be helpful). Please [edit] your question to include the copy-pasted (as text) build log.

Comment: That's all I'm getting. It just gives me undefined references to the two lua functions and then exits with the collect2.exe error as usual. Adding more functions increases the undefined references but there are no other errors.

Comment: Are you sure that the given path of option "-L" points from the current directory to the directory the library exists?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it wouldn't even be able to find the headers as the include folder is in that same folder. If the folder was invalid it would return a "cannot find -llua54" error instead.

Comment: Are you trying to build a 32-bit binary but linking against a 64-bit Lua library, or vice versa?

Comment: Turns out I was. My gcc build defaults to 32 bit and all lua versions I tried using were 64 bit. Using the 32 bit library instead fixed the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua library doesn't linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64846291/lua-library-doesnt-linking)